# Variance of $3$-dimensional vectors

Tags: 3d, covariance, variance

I am currently optimizing some code and thus, I want to replace an inefficient OpenCV function, which calculates a covariance matrix. The thing is, that I only need the trace of this covariance matrix, as such, I only need the variance, if I am not mistaken.

Well, my main problem is, that each element has an x, y and z coordinate and thus, 3 dimensions. So, my data looks like:

`[x_1, y_1, z_1], [x_2, y_2, z_2], ... [x_n, y_n, z_n]`

How can I calculate the variance of this 3D data in general - and how could I optimize it to run as fast as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally the variance of a random vector $X\in\mathbb R^m$ is
$$
\Sigma = \operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{E}( (X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T) \in\mathbb R^{m\times m}\quad\text{where } \mu=\operatorname{E}(X)\in\mathbb R^m.
$$
Thus $\Sigma$ is a symmetric non-negative-definite matrix.  Feller's book calls this the variance; some others call it the "covariance matrix" since its entries are the covariances between components of $X$.  Some of its properties are similar to those of variances of scalar-valued random variables; for example if $A\in\mathbb R^{\ell\times m}$ so that $AX$ is an $\ell\times 1$ random column vector, then $\operatorname{var}(AX) = A\Sigma A^T\in\mathbb R^{\ell\times\ell}$.

You're talking about estimating $\Sigma$ based on a sample of size $n$, with $m=3$. Regarding your data points as column vectors $\begin{bmatrix} x_k \\ y_k \\ z_k \end{bmatrix}$, for $k=1,\ldots,n$, we can let $\begin{bmatrix} \bar x \\ \bar y \\ \bar z \end{bmatrix}$ and then look at the matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} \ldots, & x_k - \bar x, & \ldots \\ \ldots, & y_k - \bar y, & \ldots \\ \ldots, & z_k - \bar z, & \ldots \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{3\times n}.
$$
Then
$$
S = \frac 1 n M M^T \in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}
$$
is the maximum-likelihood estimator of $\Sigma$ if the $3\times 1$ column vectors are from a $3$-dimensional normal distribution. The matrix
$$
\tilde S = \frac 1 {n-1} M M^T \in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}
$$
is an unbiased estimator of $\Sigma$ under far weaker assumptions.

Comment: Thank you. I am not 100% sure if I understand everything correctly. I need the trace of the covariance matrix, the covariance matrix should be symmetric, which M is not. I expected, that M should have a size of NxNx3. Do I have to use the trace of S or do I have to do even something else?

Comment: The matrix $MM^T$ is symmetric and is $3\times 3$ in your example. The trace of $S$ would probably serve your purpose, as might also the trace of $\displaystyle \tilde S$.  $\qquad$

Comment: I have implemented a small test environment and used the OpenCV implementation for comparison. I found out, that this implementation gives $MM^T$ from which I used the trace directly as result, and not $S$. Since $S$ is basically just scaling down $MM^T$ this will definitely lead to an error if the size of the vector is varying and these results are compared (both is true in my case). Since I am currently replacing the slow OpenCV implementation by my own, this means, that I really had a bug there, if I am not mistaken. So, in short, I definitely have to use $S$ and not $MM^T$?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say "the size of the vector is varying".

Comment: With the size of my vector I mean $n$ from your formulas. I have an application, which separates a huge data set into smaller ones. The data is separated multiple times into "random" subsets, by calculating and comparing the trace of the covariance matrix of these subsets, the best separation can be found. Thus, $n$ varies depending on how the subsets are separated (since they are not separated into equally sized subsets). Thus, by using $S$ (which divides by $n$) the resulting trace is uniformly scaled, since it is independent of $n$. Am I right?